# Conflict between sent messages and type column of content provider

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am sending messages using android `SmsManager.sendTextMessage(..)`
but while on reading the SMS content provider columns, I am getting the type column value 1 which should be 2 for sent messages and even on device default messaging app, my sent messages are showing as Received.

The code I am using to send the messages is

```
public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(address.get(i), null, messagetosend, null, null);
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ADDRESS, address.get(i));
values.put(BODY, messagetosend);
contentResolver.insert(Uri.parse(SMS_URI), values);
```

And I am printing the values on Logcat with this piece of code:

```
Uri allMessages = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
//Cursor cursor = managedQuery(allMessages, null, null, null, null); Both are same
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(allMessages, null, null, null, null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        Log.d(cursor.getColumnName(i) + "", cursor.getString(i) + "");
    }
    Log.d("One row finished", "**************************************************");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";
```

to

```
public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms/sent";
```

and you could also add

```
values.put("type", 2);
```

Comment: thanks..
should android not update the type column or i have to update it for every sent message?

Comment: You have to update it for every sent message.
p.s. Accept my answer :)

Comment: thankyou so much..it works :) just tell me one thing do I need to use content://sms/inbox for keep record of incoming messages?

Comment: I would prefer that instead of content://sms